# Samsung Android device is listed as modem under Windows, but want it as mass storage device

Tags: usb-connection-mode

When I plug in my Samsung phone it puts it under devices and printers it says that it is a modem. It reads Samsung CDMA technologies. I don't know how to get it to detect as a drive so I can put music and pictures on my phone. It is characterised as mass storage device and usb debugging is on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Samsung device is this?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an USB icon in the notification bar. If you expand the notification bar and click on the USB item you should be able to configure the connection mode you want.